# Gravatar doesn't work

Tags: support, gravatar

Can somebody tell me how to use this gravatar stuff? Do I have to set it for my mail address? I've set it already, but how do I set it for this site?

Comment: Syom, check a little down the page. Your question on Stack Overflow has been migrated, and if you associate your accounts, that question will become yours again.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44062/why-do-i-still-see-my-old-gravatar

Comment: @mmyers how can i associate the accounts?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/145237?tab=accounts#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

1. Sign up to [gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/)
2. Add an email address (then verify it)
3. Add an avatar to your email address
4. Click "Edit" on your Stack Overflow profile to add email address
5. Wait it out...not long.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson where? in "edit" i can't found the plase for email

Comment: You presently have a gmail address in there. You can view it at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/145237

Comment: yes, i've set it 10 days ago. but it doesn't work:( what can i do?
i try to logout, and login again, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Syom You made an account with http://gravatar.com, correct?

Comment: I can use Gravatar in stackoverflow, area 51 but not on other sites like mathematica? Why?

Answer (score 1):

I'd the same problem. If you create a Gravatar account AFTER you entered your email address in your stack overflow account, the picture doesn't change. I don't know why, but you can resolve this, by following this steps:

1. Create a Gravatar for your email
2. remove the email from your stack overflow profile
3. Click on "Save Profile"
4. enter your email in your stack overflow profile again
5. Click on "Save Profile"

Comment: I'd suspect a caching issue more than anything.

Comment: I can use Gravatar in stackoverflow, area 51 but not on other sites like mathematica? Why?