# How does stackoverflow store user sessions?

Tags: discussion

I know from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stackoverflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how) that you use Redis, and it...

```
    * Contains things like user sessions, and pending view count updates
```

Do you only store user sessions in the cache or do you use the database with it aswell (incase Redis goes down)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User sessions are stored in the database as well.

The trick is that user sessions *very rarely* change, and can thus be heavily cached.