# Why was Redis chosen over Memcache for the cache layer for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, caching, technology

From [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stackoverflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how), it is clear that the Stack Overflow team uses Redis heavily and it has been working well for them. Since there are a number of other similar solutions in the cache space, I was wondering *why* the Stack Overflow team went with Redis over Memcached (or any others).

Could anyone shed some light on this for me?

While my project is nowhere *near* the traffic volumes of Stack Overflow, I've been asked to investigate a cache solution and I thought I would ask one of the most-well respected and open groups available to see if they could share any insight into why Redis was selected.

Comment: Anecdotally, the post you linked suggests that Redis is hella fast, and the Team has experience with it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Yes, Redis _is_ hell'a fast, and I agree that the team has experience with it based on the post and the time that's passed since then, but a number of Redis vs. Memcache benchmarks I've found indicate that Memcache _might_ be a bit faster, so I was wondering what _other_ reasoning (or what reasoning in general) went  into selecting Redis. Even if the reason was "first thing we tried and it worked for us", I'd still like to know :)

Answer (score 5):

I think that they chose Redis, because Redis can do a lot more things than Memcached.

Take a look at this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11257333

Even if Memcached is a bit faster, Redis remains a good choice in regard of:

- **Persistence of data**: you do not need to warm your cache.
- **Storing data**: more manipulations, requesting, and atomic levels of storage.
- **Evolving**: Redis is actively evolving, and from my point of view that's a better bet for the future than Memcached.