# Order by reputation appears to be broken in users page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, sorting, users-page, caching

See this:

> [image]

Jon Skeet got 1505 reputation gain, while the other user got only 1500. How come Jon is not first?

Comment: Ordering on what base ? reputation ? daily visit ? no. questions attend ?

Comment: I don't understand. I only know that the `week` tab was selected

Comment: The close reason makes no sense. This is a valid bug report, even though it's by design. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's almost 4 years old. Is this still reproducible?

Comment: @S.L.Barth yes, since it's not a bug as animuson explains below. I saw same behavior 40 minutes ago on SO when looking, see [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281123/what-is-users-ordering-based-on?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment913189_281123).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The actual *order* of users is cached, but the reputation displayed under their name is not. If Jon stays ahead of Silva, then the system will eventually update the list to reorder them. The list usually updates fairly quickly, but you can browse through the list and find quite a few places where there are users "out of order." In fact, this has already updated for me.

Comment: This happens all the time; it'll update within minutes.

Comment: So a classic [tag:status-bydesign], isn't it?

Comment: May you please tell me what do you mean "cached"? I mean where exactly? In the user's device *(like cookies)*?

Comment: @Shafizadeh: [Does Stack Exchange use caching and if so, how?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69164/21960) should have the information you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

There may be a chance that you are getting it from the browser cache. as I have tried the same way and I am getting it in a descending order of reputation.

> [image: Reputations]

Comment: Yes, after like 7 mins it was correct. @animuson has already mentioned what happened

Comment: No, this is not browser cache.