# What is user's ordering based on?

Tags: support, sorting, users-page

Sometime ago I was looking for a user on Stack Overflow. I saw this:

[image]

Actually that's kind of odd for me... As you see, Gordon has the biggest reputation number this week. So why is he in the third position? In other words, what's the ordering based on?

Comment: are you looking at the horizontal or vertical order?

Comment: [It's always caching...](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) (tempted to flag as no-repro, since it's no-repro now)

Comment: @meatball it is, as of right now: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ATL2j.png

Comment: Anyway @meatball you are right, official answer confirming it is given already. The order itself is cached, while the reputation is not.

Comment: @ShadowWizard May you please tell me what do you mean "cached"? I mean where exactly? In the user's device *(like cookies)*?

Comment: @Shafizadeh no, on the server, in a database table or memory-only cache.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh .. caching on the server side is also possible? Sweet ..! Is there any related article about it?

Comment: @Shafizadeh heh, caching is what makes SE sites load so fast, it's everywhere. You can read all about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-exchange-use-caching-and-if-so-how).