# vote cast not updating immediately in vote cast but updated in profile popup

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I had voted for 40 post today.But as soon as I refreshed my profile page.In User name drop link pop-up my vote cast is showing 40 count but not in the below vote cast heading. There it is just showing 16 count. After 10 times of refreshing it's showing 40 count. But why it is not updating immediately in the vote cast heading.

Comment: Caching. There is always caching to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to provide the fastest possible response times, we developed StackOverflow to cache aggressively and on multiple layers.

In particular, the user drop down fills its content via an AJAX call and the user page is generated directly by the server. The two routes are different and the second has a <strike>2</strike> 5 minutes cache.

Read more about our caching strategy here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69172/131112