# Why doesn't this question appear under tagged questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, caching

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162290/symbol-literal-or-a-method) some minutes ago, and I can reload that page to make sure it's there, but I cannot see it appear under the newest questions tagged "ruby". It is already several minutes ago. Why doesn't it appear?

**Update** After about ten minutes, I can finally see it appear. Why is this the case? Is there some delaying mechanism?

Comment: I see it there. Are you sure you're on the correct tab? (newest)

Comment: *"Is there some delaying mechanism?"* Yes, caching.

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: [Kinda like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-overflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how).