# Page download speed of Stack Overflow. What's the tech and trick?

Tags: support, performance

I am baffled by the way Stack Overflow pages are loaded. Even through a mobile connection.(Where download speed is 8kbps & I am not talking about the mobile site. I am taking about using the mobile as a modem and accessing Stack Overflow through a desktop browser).

What makes Stack Overflow pages download so instantaneous? I have seen AJAX coming into play all the time. This is made more explicit when I see the header and footer remaining fixed and content changes slowly (Thanks to mobile connection). And they also use something like `Stackexchange.ready()`. What is that about?

Overall what do they use and how are they doing it so good?

I am really curious. The only other site I have seen that shows this kind of optimization is Google's main page.

Comment: Cache, not AJAX. Lots of Cache.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: No that can't be right. Caching is only the answer when the question is about why something *doesn't* work.

Comment: [Does Stack Overflow use caching and if so, how?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-overflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how)

Comment: Ok, thats a start. Can you send me link to some heavy-duty tutorial on caching?

Comment: That would be off-topic here @SwaroopNagendra.

Comment: One thing to note about the fast network-performance of Stack is that the pages tend not to be bloated with lots of unnecessary fluff.

Comment: No common. I am curious. Some developers might be there who would answer it.

Comment: Also worth to mention that a recent change slowed things down, the homepage now take 1-2 seconds to load where it used to take less than a second before. Injecting old posts in the "interesting" view is causing it, hope the team will fix it at some point. :(

Comment: @JonW this, and oscillation.

Comment: @Andrew Barber -- No, I have seen every page has about 3 to 4 ads and even those ads will load in a jiffy on turtle connections

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra Well, the ads are just simple images. A handful of those isn't a big thing.

Comment: [spam] -- I will present a talk about this subject at http://devday.pl and http://webtechcon.de this year.