# Does Stack Overflow use redis for output caching?

Tags: discussion, caching

I've [read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-overflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how/69172#69172) that Stack Overflow uses Redis for distributed caching and also Output Caching but was curious as to whether a custom OutputCache Provider is used to store the output cache in the Redis layer?

Comment: Did you try asking in a comment to [the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69172/152859)? (here in Meta you can comment anywhere even with 1 rep)