# Stack Overflow home page shows 2 different values for my reputation

Tags: support, reputation, homepage

When I moved to Stackoverflow home page, there was a variation in points in near my name.  I tired refreshing but still it is not updated.

[image]

Comment: Probably due to caching.

Comment: It's always due to caching...

Comment: @Stijn No tried logging in another browser, still same behavior.

Comment: Have you any idea how often the Stack Overflow main page is served per second? No way that page can reasonably show your reputation in real time. The information is cached server side, per question.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan: We are not talking about your browser cache here.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan changing your browser doesn't refresh the server-side cache

Comment: @MartijnPieters Got it.  Out of curiosity may I know how often(time interval) it is getting refreshed in server side?

Comment: For some more detail, see [Does Stack Overflow use caching and if so, how?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-overflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how)

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan: I have no idea. Check back on that page every few minutes and see if the discrepancy disappears?

Comment: Likely not a bug, but agree it's weird behavior.

Comment: Caching or not, it'd still be nice if we showed the *same value* throughout the *same* page.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Guess it must around 20+ minutes, still it is not updated.  Anyway thanks for the link Bart.