# New questions disappearing after a refresh. Is this a bug?

Tags: support, live-refresh

I noticed several times now, that, when I have a tag filter open, I get a bar telling me that new questions have arrived (example would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b but it doesn't really matter, because this behaviour is the same for other tags as well).

When you click on that bar, the questions appear in the list. But when I hit the refresh button on the browser, those questions are suddenly gone. When I hit the refresh button a littler bit later again, the questions are back in the list.

Is this a bug or a problem with cache timing in the browser (using Firefox)?

I noticed that, when I hit refresh several times, there seem to be some delay included, probalby to avoid server strain. Might be a side effect of this.

**update**

I just tested this on Meta and there this does not happen. So it seems only on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is not a bug. That is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

You get live notifications through the websockets. When you refresh the page you get a **cached result** that is not as up-to-date as the "live-stream".

Comment: And why is this not the same on meta?

Comment: It is the same. Meta is just not that heavily cached.

Comment: @Devolus caching is timing dependent; there isn't anything particularly different on meta

Comment: @Devolus in particular, when you refresh on meta it is probably a **cache miss**, so does actual work and gets the fresh data; on SO, you are likely to be looking at the same stuff as others, so get a **cache hit**, reusing existing data

Comment: @MarcGravell, but there is a difference, because on meta I don't see this effect. An explanation might be juergens comment.

Comment: @Devolus which is why I already added more detail

Comment: @MarcGravell I didn't know you were using cache miss/hit technique, maybe worth adding that to the [big detailed post about caching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69172/152859)? On quick and slower look, couldn't find it mentioned in there.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd on the list-by-tag pages? we cache the bejeezus out of that