# How long does it take for question information to be updated on Advance Search Screen?

Tags: support, search

Is there delay on question information to be undated on Advance Search Screen?

Screenshot shows question [How does the SQL IN keyword work when you use a select within a select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052773/how-does-the-sql-in-keyword-work-when-you-use-a-select-within-a-select) been asked 31m ago but does not have any answers or votes. But when looking at the question it has 2 answers and one has been accepted. First answer was provided 7 minutes after questions created.

[image]

Is this a bug or just a lag on my system that is generating this?

Comment: The obligatory: [it is caching!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-overflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how)

Comment: Apparently it sometimes takes longer than 7 minutes.  Searches are fact because they rely on indexes.  You have a choice between very fast and slightly out of date searches, or real-time results and searches that take many minutes to come back.

Comment: Well sometime between 31 minutes after create time and 38 minutes after create time it has been updated, it now shows correct information on search screen. So it has taken at least 23 minutes after first answer was added to when it appeared correctly on the search.