# Find own non-posted questions?

Tags: feature-request, draft

It happens to me that I start answering a question, and hit some snag. So I abandon the partial answer, knowing that I can go back to it later and complete it (many thanks for that!).

But I variously use my tablet, the PC at home or another one at work to participate here. And some of the sites (MSE is a particular culprit here) often have *hundreds* of new questions a day, and the original question (if not "favorite") is thus hopelessly lost.

Is there a simple way to get at a list of all of my drafts?

Comment: You can favorite the question, as a workaround.

Comment: Are they stored as local caches or on the site? Maybe you can look through the browser?

Comment: I just confirmed there is only one answer draft per site, the latest overriding the previous. @mhlester neither of those, they are stored in [Redis cache](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69172/152859) which is not accessible to us in any way.