# Help Center page search results appear to be outdated by the tag email change

Tags: bug, status-review, tags, search, help-center

I see that email notifications for tag subscriptions [was recently removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/19177/revisions), but when I search the Help Center on various sites, the search results still indicate "email" as a possibility, even when the destination page does not.

Search result snippet:

> **How do I use tags to find topics I'm interested in?**

> If you'd like to be notified of new activity within a certain tag, you can subscribe via email or RSS by ...

while the [linked Help Center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) itself says:

> If you'd like to be notified of new activity within a certain tag, you can subscribe via RSS by ...

Is it [caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-exchange-use-caching-and-if-so-how)? A bug?

Comment: "email notifications for tag subscriptions was recently removed" – The feature itself was removed long ago, as far as I know. The [corresponding Help Center page](/help/interesting-topics) was just very out of date until I recently updated it. (Also, I can confirm that I'm seeing the same thing in the search results. [I'm going to guess caching is indeed to blame](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)... :P)

Comment: Thanks, @V2Blast, I figured! Hopefully we can find the right handle to flush the right cache! :)

Comment: Just FYI to the staff who looks at this (and CC @V2Blast with the recent edit), I checked a few sites' help search results; more than just Meta.SE is affected -- I *assume* all of them. Thanks!